# Hoo to Rerun failed test cases in jenkins using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, automation, pytest

How to rerun failed test cases in jenkins using Python - pytest and selenium? I'm able to run the last failed TCs using
python3 -m pytest -v --lf path/of/tests/test_cases.py But, i'm not sure to implement the same in jenkins. Can someone help me with this.